# grails and springsecurity config problem

Tags: grails, spring-security

Greetings!
I'm trying to implement SringSecurity in my project and use Static URL rules.

I have a FamilyController and would like to restrict access to all it's actions, but no matter what I try they remain accessible without authentication. Now, I tried to secure them with annotations and that works like a charm. But deciding against that  I removed all the annotations and decided to use Static URL rules instead.

The very top of Config.groovy file looks like this:

```
    import grails.plugins.springsecurity.SecurityConfigType

grails.plugins.springsecurity.securityConfigType = SecurityConfigType.InterceptUrlMap

grails.plugins.springsecurity.iterceptUrlMap = [
        '/family/**' : ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY']
]
```

... but for the life of me I can't see what I'm missing. 
Will appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you spelled iNterceptUrlMap incorrectly.  You are missing the 'n'

Comment: ...I've been always afraid of something like that :-( Now the world knows I can't type ;-) Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @vector, no problem.  sometimes all it takes is another pair of eyes.